# Entity Framework One to One relation?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, restier

I've generated my tables from my diagram :

[Database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvp2U.png)
But I dunno why, EF will generate this in the Origin model:

```
public virtual ICollection<Container> Containers { get; set; }
```

In the Container model :

```
public int OriginID { get; set; }
public virtual Origin Origin { get; set; }
```

and in the context :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Origin>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Containers)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Origin)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

But a Container Object CAN ONLY have one Origin object.

How can I remove the collection to have only one instance of my object in the origin object ?

Because actually my Restier service is retrieving me origins objects with a collection of only ONE container.

So the collection is totally useless.

Do you guys have any idea?

Thank you very much

Comment: Shouldn't there be a relationship between both of the primary keys?

Answer (score 0):

Because origins could well be related to a lot of containers - they don't know it. What you have is a one(origin) to many(container).
Say I have origin with ID 1 and container A with originID 1. What would prevent me from adding container B with the same originID? If you insist on a 1-to-1 relation, try adding keys to both models - origin should know it's only related to the one container and vice-versa.

TD;DR: Add ContainerID to the Origin table.

Comment: Well, my origin table can either have a nullable "container" or a nullable "flow". But only one. That's why I need a 1-1 to retrieve easily my data. Actually what I get is : {
      "ID":1,"Flows":[
        
      ],"Containers":[
        {
          "ID":1,"Name":"M3","Width":0.0,"Length":0.0,"Height":0.0,"Volume":0.0,"OriginID":1,"DestinationID":13,"DisplayName":"Mercuras"
        }
      ]
    }

Answer (score 0):

i think that the best way to add a one-to-one relation is have a primary key that is also a foreign key.

( the Origin Id should reference the Container id)